# running wordpress blog as directory location within nginx server configured for rails

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, ruby-on-rails

I've been running a site on puma / rails setup under nginx. Now we have to setup wordpress under path /blog, i.e.

`www.mysite.com` is the rails app, and `www.mysite.com/blog` is the wordpress blog.

the location setup done for Wordpress blog is as follows

```
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:///var/run/website/website.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.bhokaal.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    #server_name www.bhokaal.com;

    access_log /home/bhokaal/bhokaal.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/bhokaal/bhokaal.com/logs/error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.bhokaal.com_cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.bhokaal.com.key;

    root /home/bhokaal/bhokaal-website/public/;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location /blog {
       root /home/bhokaal/bhokaal-blog/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 500m;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
}
```

my assumption is that /blog get's processed by PHP while rest goes to upstream puma server.

We get a rather cryptic error when we access `www.bhokaal.com/blog`

```
2017/12/08 12:10:02 [error] 19193#19193: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 49.207.56.120, server: , request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock:", host: "www.bhokaal.com"
```

Nginx, PHP-FPM and Puma are all running under the same user, so I don't think it is user permissions problem as pointed out by most of blogs I referred on this problem.

Comment: Is WordPress installed into a directory called `blog`? i.e. `/home/bhokaal/bhokaal-blog/blog/`?

Comment: wordpress is installed in `/home/bhokaal/bhokaal-blog/`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `alias` to map URIs which begin with `/blog` to a root that ends with something else. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more.

The cleanest solution is to use a nested `location` block. The `^~` modifier on the outer block avoids any side-effects. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

```
location ^~ /blog {
    alias /home/bhokaal/bhokaal-blog;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /blog/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

Avoid `try_files` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97), and note [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: what does this line mean `if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }` and why do we need it? same for `if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /blog/index.php last; }`

Comment: it's become a bit more confusing now that after applying this config I get a 403 on /blog

Comment: I missed out the `index index.php;` statement. See updated answer.

Comment: The `if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }` statement is in response to [this issue](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php), but using `if` instead of `try_files`.

Comment: okay so we're saying "if the request is not a directory try rewriting to blog/index.php as last option?" and if the file name does not exist return a 404?

Comment: sorry for flooding the comments but with this configuration we again get the "Primary script unkown" error

Comment: Check the access log, because these `location` blocks should be protected from that error. It is usual with WordPress to send everything to `index.php` so that it can implement pretty permalinks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69955/discussion-between-anadi-misra-and-richard-smith).

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me,

installing wordpress under `/home/bhokaal/bhokaal-website/public/blog` i.e. the rails public folder

adding the location and PHP blocks as usual

```
location  /blog {
    index   index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```